# Identification of items by use of wildcards

Tags: r, wildcard

I have a dataset with several hundret items, looking like this

```
ID    01_ab_dog 01_ae_cat 02_ae_dog 02_hg_horse 01_oq_cat etc ...
1     1         3         5         8           10            ...
2     654       12        89        7           112           ...
3     4         9         4         978         64            ...
4     19        86        95        46          8             ...
```

I am looking to identify all items that include the word - let´s say - 'cat'. A solution that includes wildcards (e.g. 01_**_cat) would be great and I was looking for something like this but I did not suceed. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: A better search term than "wildcards" is "regular expression".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with `item`. To get all columns with `cat`, you could use `grepl`.

```
df <- data.frame(ab = 1, b = 1, cat_a = 1, bb_bbcat = 1)
df[, grepl("cat", names(df))]
# cat_a bb_bbcat
# 1     1        1
```